# Opened DIV in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, this is the question. 
I have 4 DIV's. 
Inside that DIV's i have text. 
DIV's are small, so on the bottom i have link "show more". 
When i press that link i need that DIV to be opened in new tab, but the point is that in new tab i need to have all 4 DIV's but just full opened that DIV i was clicked on first page. 
Any ideas?

**Does anybody know how can i make that??**

Or, second solution is that when i click on "show more" link, i get the popup window wit whole text with close button in right corner? Anyone?

Comment: make a new page with the four tabs on and if you are using jquery tabs you can just pass the hash id to the url and it will be opened on that tab

Comment: your question is not clear. you mean new tab inside page, or new browser tab? if new browser tab, you need a link to a page that only shows that div, either because that's the only visible html on the page or because param in url or other data-transfer mechanism (postmessage/localstorage/cookie) tells the page to do that.

Comment: I would suggest implementing your second solution using a jQueryUI dialog.

Comment: This question is unclear

Comment: Very good Pete, but how can i pass the hash id to the url? Sory on my bad english, that's my problem here..Thank you brothers for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would avoid popup and a new tab since judging by your question there's no need for that. I would perhaps, place that hidden content inside your div (for example below your read more link) that would slide up/down using jQuery on 'Readmore' link click.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eFELf/)

js

```
 $('.readmore').click(function(){    
        $('.hidden').slideUp(200);    
        var divToShow = $(this).parent().find('.hidden');    
        divToShow.slideDown(300);    
    });
```

html

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum est dolorum Lorem ipsum est dolorum Lorem ipsum est dolorum</p>
    <span class="readmore">Read more</span>
    <div class="hidden">This is some hidden content</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum est dolorum Lorem ipsum est dolorum Lorem ipsum est dolorum</p>
    <span class="readmore">Read more</span>
    <div class="hidden">This is some hidden content</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum est dolorum Lorem ipsum est dolorum Lorem ipsum est dolorum</p>
    <span class="readmore">Read more</span>
    <div class="hidden">This is some hidden content</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum est dolorum Lorem ipsum est dolorum Lorem ipsum est dolorum</p>
    <span class="readmore">Read more</span>
    <div class="hidden">This is some hidden content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: An example of `slideToggle` instead of `slideDown` - http://jsfiddle.net/eFELf/1/

Comment: Slavenko brate hvala si dobar si covjek, ne znam kako da objasnim ovoj braci na engleskom :))

Comment: @bostaq_sb9 hahaha carski, samo cepaj :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jquery UI dialog for opening a popup and displaying the content of div in it.

Check this [link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated) for reference

Answer (score -1):

First you can make all your div's content hide and when clicked on show more the function show make it full version.You should first make some css:

```
   .hidden { display: none};

   .unhidden { display: block; }
```

Script example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function unhide(divID) {
      var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
       item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
              }
                           }
    </script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp this site may help you